Android send implicit broadcast with data_uri not work
My receiver is registered in manifest (my phone is android 14)
  <receiver android:name="a.b.c.MyReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          <data android:scheme="myscheme"
            android:host="myhost"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

It can receive intent if use explicit intent like this

adb shell am broadcast -n com.my.package/a.b.c.MyReceiver --es mykey "myvalue"

but if I use implicit intent like

adb shell am broadcast -d "myscheme://myhost" --es mykey "myvalue"

MyReceiver cannot receive the intent.
How can I change my code to make MyReceiver receive implicit intent.

On Android 8+ (API level 26+), you would have to register your Receiver dynamically. They started restricting manifest-registered Receivers with that version: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts.

@MikeM. You are right,  i register it dynamically and now it can receive implicit intent. and i find if i only register it in manifest, it can only receive explicit intent (whether app is launched), if i only  register it dynamically, it can only receive implicit intent. if i register it both in manifest and in code dynamically. it can receive both explicit and implicit intent.

Yeah, you should always prefer explicit broadcasts, though, unless you really have to use implicit ones, for some reason.

Part 1 (Difference Between Implicit and Explicit)
Explicit broadcasts offer a more secure and efficient approach, especially in modern Android development.



Feature
Implicit Broadcast
Explicit Broadcast




Security
Can be intercepted by any app.
Delivered only to the specified app.


Performance
Involves multiple apps (broadcast storm).
Involves only one specific receiver.


Restrictions (Oreo+)
Many implicit broadcasts are restricted.
No restrictions on explicit broadcasts.


Use Case
Useful for system-wide broadcasts.
Best for app-to-app or internal communication.




Part 2 (Google guidelines for Registering Explicit Broadcast)
Dynamic Registration Example (Recommended for Explicit Broadcasts)
In Code (Without Manifest):
val intentFilter = IntentFilter("com.example.SOME_ACTION")

Register receiver dynamically
registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter)
Unregister when done (e.g., in onDestroy)
unregisterReceiver(myReceiver)
Sending Explicit Broadcast:
intent.setPackage("com.example.myapp") // Targeting specific package
sendBroadcast(intent)

Careful when and where you register and unregister the receiver for instance if you registered a receiver in the onCreate() using the activity as context then you should unregister it in onDestroy() other you end up leaking the receiver outside of the activity context. If you register a receiver in onResume(), you should call onPause() before the next onResume() so that you don’t register it again (If you do no wish to receive broadcasts when you are paused, this can save on system resources). It is better not to unregister in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), since this can work if the user changed screen.
Note:
If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction. In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.
Reference link - https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers
